# HTML how to do successive file uploads?

Tags: javascript, html, file, input

How do I make a file input element do successive uploads?

That is, I want the user to be able to click the upload button and upload file. Then I want the user to be able to click the same upload button and add another file to the uploaded files instead of overwriting all the current files.

I'm assuming this will require some javascript. How do I do this in JS?

I've tried using a

```
 <input type="file" multiple>
```

element, but it doesn't do what I want. I want to be able to add files to the existing list. The multiple input element overwrites the existing list.

Comment: kindly show your efforts. SO is not a coding service to offer you readymade code.

Comment: "add another file to the uploaded files instead of overwriting all the current files" — Whether or not the files get overwritten when new files are uploaded will depend on the server side code responsible to extracting the files from the HTTP request and storing them.

Comment: Quentin is right this is a server side issue. If you submit to the same processing file/endpoint/etc. each time it will write over what you have unless you add in handling.

Comment: @Stavm I've added what I've tried

Comment: @Quentin I want a page that displays the files the user has selected before it sends to the server. This is something relatively common on websites- you upload files, it adds a thumbnail to a file list near the input element that you can manage, all before you submit the request to the server.

Comment: @DFL — So you want to add something to the DOM when you upload a file? That doesn't seem to have anything to do with overwriting anything. Do you have code to add that thing to the DOM already? Does the code you have written overwrite whatever you already have in the DOM? We can't tell you why it does that if you don't show us a [mcve].

Comment: @Quentin This is something I'm totally unfamiliar with. I was wondering first if there was a vanilla HTML way to do this, which I don't think there is. The plain html file input element overwrites what is currently selected, so it doesn't allow you to append files to the existing list. 

From there, I have no idea how to add the files to the DOM via JS and make them submittable to the server. I'm not sure where to start or how to even search for it. When I search for "successive file upload", nothing useful comes up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps I misunderstand what you're asking for, but I believe this may be what you want:

```
<input type="file" multiple>
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-multiple

Edit:
Although ugly IMO and 3rd party, this appears to have the behavior you want:
https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/jquery-ui.html

Comment: That allows me to upload multiple files at one time. Instead, I want to be able to select 1 file, click OK, and then click the upload button again to add another file.

With the multiple tag, it just overwrites whatever was already selected. I want to add to that selection instead.

Comment: @DFL Ah, the "multiple" input only selects multiple files when you hold down control or shift to select the files, right. When you do that, the input just says, e.g. "11 files selected." You want to show a list of all the files. That makes sense from a user-experience standpoint.

What you want will require custom JavaScript that will act on the HTML DOM to display the list of files, among whatever other logic is required to upload this list of files if you are allowing the user to add files to the list 1 by 1. So I think you'll have to take a crack at writing this, or use 3rd party code.

Comment: I have no idea where to start. Do you have suggestions for keywords I can search for this with or possible libraries that can do this?

Comment: @DFL I searched for "multifile upload widget" and found this:
https://blueimp.github.io/jQuery-File-Upload/jquery-ui.html

It's quite ugly IMO and I can't vouch for its quality, but it has the behavior you describe of adding files to a list before uploading them. So you may want to use it, or look at its code to get an idea of what it's doing.

Comment: @DFL Glad it helped. I edited my original answer, if you'd be willing to upvote and/or mark it as accepted I would appreciate it :)